# Capturing hostname across multiple sites with Javascript

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, parsing, dns

I'm trying to capture the hostname, without 'www." or '.com'. At this point i'm able to capture what i'm looking for using the following:

```
var host = document.location.host;
var parts = host.split('\.');
var result = parts[1];
var partner = result+"_block";
```

This will be used across 20+ sites and that number will grow, my concern is that some sites might not use redirects to "www" and if the domain appears as example.com vs www.example.com then I will be capturing "com" instead of "example". Is there any better solution for resolving this without using conditional statements?

**UPDATE**

There is no standard way of doing this from what I can tell, so I just added a conditional statement like so:

```
var result;
var host = document.location.hostname;
var parts = host.split('\.');
if(parts[0] == 'www' || 'beta' || 'm'){
    result = parts[1]
}else{
    result = parts[0]
}
```

Comment: what about example.co.uk? You'd be capturing `co`...